# Chrome extension: execution order of multiple content_script injections

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension with the following content_script Array in the `manifest.json`:

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://*.xxxxx.com/xxx/index.php*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "js/libs/purify.min.js",
        "js/basics.js",
        "js/main.js"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    },
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://*.xxxxx.com/xxx/index.php?page=subpage*"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "js": ["js/subpage.js"]
    }
  ]
```

So I want `js/libs/purify.min.js`, `js/basics.js` and `js/main.js` to be injected on all pages. In the `?page=subpage` sub page, I want the extension to additionally load `js/subpage.js`.

Now when I run this on my computer, this works perfectly. However, *some users* report the extension throws an error on `?page=subpage` saying that things, that are defined in `basics.js` aren't defined: `ReferenceError: CONST is not defined`

I checked over TeamViewer with one of them if they're doing something wrong, but clearly Chrome is loading the `subpage.js` first. After completely removing the extension on said user's PC and reinstalling it, it worked like intended. However, after a restart of the PC, the same issue occured.

Am I wrong in assuming that content scripts should be loaded in the given order? It works for the majority of my users, but for some, Chrome seems to be insisting on loading the subpage script first.